# jQuery live clock works but freezes browser?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

So I made a little script for a clock, and used setInterval to make it live.
It works fine, but the problem is it freezes my browser after a minute or so. I'm a little stuck as I don't know how to solve this. Can someone help please?
Here is the code:

```
$(function liveClock(){

var dt = new Date();
var hh = dt.getHours();
var mm = dt.getMinutes();
var ss = dt.getSeconds();
var ampm = "";

if (ss <= 9){ ss = "0"+dt.getSeconds() }
if (mm <= 9){ mm = "0"+dt.getMinutes() }
if (hh > 12){
    hh = hh - 12;
    ampm = "pm";
}else{
    ampm = "am";
}

$("p").html( hh + ":" + mm + ":" + ss + " " + ampm );

setInterval(function(){
  liveClock();
}, 1000);

});
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: why is it wrapped in `$()`?

Comment: shouldn't it be? it's the only script I have on the page

Comment: setInterval(...) is being called every time you invoke liveClock().  Either change your algorithm or consider using setTimeout(...) instead.

Comment: I suppose if you're waiting for the document to be ready it's fine, but you could equally put your script block as your last tag in the body and get the same effect for free.

Comment: @JohnSheridan looks good. I'll live it for like an hour to be sure. 
jk thank you :D

Answer (score 5):

Every time `liveClock` runs, it starts an interval running.

You run it manually. You have an interval running that runs it every second.

After 1 second, it gets called again. You now have two intervals calling it every second.

After 2 seconds, it gets called again twice. You now have 4 intervals calling it every second.

3 seconds. 8 intervals.

4 seconds. 16 intervals.

etc.

---

- Replace `$()` with `setInterval`
- Remove `setInterval` from inside the function

Answer (score 0):

I think it's because your setting `setInterval` every time the function is run, and so after a minute you have 60 timers going.

You can make it work correctly by only setting `setInterval` once like so:

```
function liveClock(){
    var dt = new Date();
    var hh = dt.getHours();
    var mm = dt.getMinutes();
    var ss = dt.getSeconds();
    var ampm = "";

    if (ss <= 9){ ss = "0"+dt.getSeconds() }
    if (mm <= 9){ mm = "0"+dt.getMinutes() }
    if (hh > 12){
        hh = hh - 12;
        ampm = "pm";
    }else{
        ampm = "am";
    }
    $("p").html( hh + ":" + mm + ":" + ss + " " + ampm );
}

$(function() {
    setInterval(function(){
        liveClock();
    }, 1000);
});
```

JSFiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/76328/

Or try exchanging it for `setTimeout()` instead which will only happen once.

Answer (score -2):

Try this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script src="Scripts/jquery-1.4.1.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        function liveClock() {
            var today = new Date();
            var h = today.getHours();
            var m = today.getMinutes();
            var s = today.getSeconds();
            m = checkTime(m);
            s = checkTime(s);

            $("p").html(h + ":" + m + ":" + s);
            var t = setTimeout(function () { liveClock() }, 500);
        }
        function checkTime(i) {
            if (i < 10) { i = "0" + i };  // add zero in front of numbers < 10
            return i;
        }
    </script>
</head>
```

```
<p></p>
```

[Fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/mehtaniravm/5QD8J/)

This code doesn't freezes browser and I've checked it and it works perfectly. Hope to get vote up for the code.